# How to fetch data from multiple APIs using RxJava with retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava. I want to fetch data from the JSON API. Assume there are two APIs, API 1 and API 2. We fetch a JSON object "mediaId" from API 1. Now, I want to fetch JSON from API 2 with "mediaId". How can I achieve this using RxJava, along with retrofit in Android?

```
public void gettdata(final Listerner listerner){

    postitemses= new ArrayList<>();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.mytrendin.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APiService networkAPI = retrofit.create(APiService.class);

    Observable<List<Postitems>> observable = networkAPI.getFriendObservable()
                                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    observable.subscribe(new Observer<List<Postitems>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

            listerner.onFailure("oops... Something went wrong");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Postitems> postitemsList1) {

            Postitems postitems;
            for (int i=0;i<postitemsList1.size();i++){
                postitems = new Postitems();
                int id = postitemsList1.get(i).getId();
                String title = postitemsList1.get(i).getTitle().getRendered();
                String shortdesc= postitemsList1.get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered();
                String mediaid= postitemsList1.get(i).getFeatured_media();
                String authorid= postitemsList1.get(i).getAuthor();
                String date = postitemsList1.get(i).getDate();
                String slug = postitemsList1.get(i).getSlug();
                Log.i("Hello-slug",""+slug);
                String[] mediaurl= mydata(mediaid);
                Log.i("Hello-mediaurl",""+mediaurl);
                postitems.setId(id);
                postitems.setDate(date);
                postitems.setSlug(""+slug);
                postitems.setPostExcerpt(shortdesc);
                postitems.setPostTitle(title);
                postitemses.add(postitems);

            }
            listerner.showpostitems(postitemses);

        }
    });


}




public String[] mydata(String mediaid){


    final String[] mediaurl = new String[1];
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://www.mytrendin.com")
            .build();
    APiService aPiService = retrofit.create(APiService.class);
    Call<Postitems> call = aPiService.getmediaurl(mediaid);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Postitems>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Postitems> call, Response<Postitems> response) {

            Postitems postitemsList1 = response.body();
            mediaurl[0] =postitemsList1.getGuid().getRendered();
           // mediaurl[0][0] =postitemsList1.get(0).getGuid().getRendered();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Postitems> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    return mediaurl;
```

}

error occured

https://www.mytrendin.com
05-09 03:42:09.227 15315-15315/?     D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
                                           --------- beginning of crash
```

05-09 03:42:09.228 15315-15315/?     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.mytrendin.mytrendin,     PID: 15315
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException:     Attempt to invoke virtual method           .mytrendin.dashboard.utils.Po        stitems$Guid         (ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Have you done something already? post your code so we can help you from what you have done

Comment: Try to check https://github.com/eurosecom/Attendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/attendance/fragments/RetrofitFragment.java in method onListContributorsWithFullUserInfoClicked() i call 2 retrofitservices ziped by Rx zip operator.

Comment: Watch https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/README.md#4-networking-with-retrofit--rxjava-using-zip-flatmap

Comment: chain your requests and on the callback of the first call the second. Look into the observable pattern and how to handle those callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can  use the merge operator along with the IO scheduler.By definition,merge can combine multiple Observables into one by merging their emissions.here is an example,

```
Observable<Integer> odds = Observable.just(1, 3, 5).subscribeOn(someScheduler);
Observable<Integer> evens = Observable.just(2, 4, 6);

Observable.merge(odds, evens)
          .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer item) {
            System.out.println("Next: " + item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
        }
    });
```

Output :

Next: 1

Next: 3

Next: 5

Next: 2

Next: 4

Next: 6

Sequence complete.

Something like this in your case,

```
public Observable<Data> getMergedData() {
  return Observable.merge(
    networkRepository.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
    networkRepository.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  );
}
```

> Alright there is another way to solve this, first create a observable for both API, then subscribe and observe changes from your first API subscription.Next create a PublishSubject instance. Which is useful because,once an Observer has subscribed, emits all subsequently observed items to the subscriber.For example publish string values from the api response.

```
private PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();


subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).filter((s) -> s.size() > 0).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String str) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
```

---

Then to trigger the observable call onNext from the subject.

```
subject.onNext("some data from api");
```

Advantages, very flexible to changes to anywhere in your class scope.

Hope this helps.

for the below snippet

```
  call.enqueue(new Callback<Postitems>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Postitems> call, Response<Postitems> response) {

            Postitems postitemsList1 = response.body();
            mediaurl[0] =postitemsList1.getGuid().getRendered();
           // mediaurl[0][0] =postitemsList1.get(0).getGuid().getRendered();
//use the concept of publish subject here, which i detailed in answer, example
subject.onNext(postitemsList1.getGuid().getRendered());
//the string data will be passed to the above observable for the subject instance.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Postitems> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: hope this helps you getting more insight!

Comment: I want to use odds result in evens how do I do that. Please tell

Comment: i am little confused, are you referring to parallzation of the execution, because the above operation is sychronous

Comment: then why not run the first one, then on subscription, use that result

Comment: Can you please check the code once ... as I passed mediaid to mydata() method and want to return url from that ... is it possible there please check once .

Comment: but its not returning anything and app get crashed

Comment: there can be two reasons , probably your api is faulty, post the error

Comment: put a log, in the enqueue block response and tell me what you see, if nothing, then your server needs revision

Comment: error vague, but something is not initialized. hence the null pointer, please debug your code, one step a time. it helps,

Comment: this line is the error, mediaurl[0] =postitemsList1.getGuid().getRendered();

Comment: replace with subject.onNext(response.body()); with the publish subject i created.